# I need to host node js through python

Tags: python, node.js, client-server

```
var util = require('util'); 
var exec = require('child_process').spawn; 
var run = exec('/usr/bin/python', ['-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '9002']); 
run.stdout.on('data', function(data){ 
    console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString()); 
    }); 
run.stderr.on('data', function (data) { 
    console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString()); 
    });
```

test.py

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=9002)
```

I am new to node js and python just i want do communicate between node js to python with localhost. A simple python script with localhost url to hit node js url after running node js scrpit whih call python script in node and host the same on web browser.

Comment: Why is the web browser part of this problem? Have you done any research about web servers in either of those languages? Please show what you've tried, StackOverflow isn't a code writing / tutorial service

Comment: above one is the node js script

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend a shell script to run your individual processes. It's not clear why you want to start python from Node

Comment: Its part of my project so im going to host communication between both langauges

Comment: And, back to my question - Have you tried to research anything on that? What have you found? Is something like `socket.io` a library that would be useful to you?

Comment: Above one is an python script which want to communicate with node js

Comment: And please [edit] your question. Comments are not meant to be used for code

Comment: Yes i tried that but could not make it

Comment: Well, your first problem... Your bottle server is never ran. Your node process only starts python simple http server

Comment: Then how could i make that?

Comment: If i run node js it shoul not hitting url

Comment: Your ultimate goal is still unclear. What is the server and what is the client? Are both languages both a client and a server? If so, it does not appear the node code is a server. If you want to run the python script from node, then give the correct arguments to the `exec` function to actually *run your script*

Comment: Python program should run in node js

Comment: I understand that. And you are running a python process, but not the one you wrote. So, how would you run your bottle server from the command line? Then, compare that with the code you wrote in the Node script

Comment: Then what should have to do now? How should i get connect both languages?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I see the problem. Your code works.

1) Make sure you access `localhost:9002`
2) If you meant to run your bottle code, then use

```
var run = exec('/usr/bin/python', ['/path/to/bottle_server.py']);
```

[image: img1]

As for communicating back and forth between the Python code and the Node.js code, then you need sockets. Some libraries to look at could include `socket.io` or use a messaging queue like `zmq`.

If you want one-way communication to your python API, then you need to perform HTTP requests to `http://localhost:9002` from the Node code. Alternatively, Node is very much capable of the same functionality you've included in the Python code on its own.

**EDIT**

Regarding below comments, here is an updated script. You need to `inherit` the parent's `stdout` and `stderr`, otherwise, as you see in the image above, it thinks python is printing to `stderr`

```
var util = require('util');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var run = spawn('/usr/bin/python', ['-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '9002'],
    { stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit' ] });

run.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

[image: img2]

Comment: What are the steps i should fallow? Actually im running this script in eclipse so getting confused.

Comment: 1) Run Node script normally 2) open `http://localhost:9002`. That's it. I don't know what else you wanted.

Comment: I need url should hit on the console after running node js script which call Python script.

Comment: It means after running node js script mentioned url should display on the console.  But it not displaying. That s the question

Comment: You won't get `"Serving on <Public IP address>"` as your output without some custom python code that actually gets that information. I've updated with what I think you've asked

Comment: Thank you so much it will help me lot.